# Find index of the element in Java 8 stream foreach

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

There are already some posts looks relative to this, I went through them, but those not solved my problem:

I have a method and some logic, I have to do **code optimize using streams**.

My method is: (here I am trying to print the emails in a formatted way)

```
public static StringBuilder printEmailsListFormat(ArrayList<String> a) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 3 ==0)
        {
            sb.append(String.format("%-45s", a.get(i)));
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        else
            sb.append(String.format("%-45s", a.get(i)));
    }
    return sb;
}
```

I have to optimize this code.

Comment: optimize what exactly? this is the fastest way available already.

Comment: What exactly do you have to optimize? Performance? Readability? I have a first recommendation: Don't name a method that does not print anything `printEmailsListFormat`.

Comment: "I have to optimize using streams". But why?

Comment: Streams are not very suitable when using branching conditions. They are also not aware of the list indices. Although it is possible, this is not a good candidate for converting to use streams.

Comment: If you want to optimize anything, move the first `sb.append` before the `if/else`

Comment: @tobias_k also chain `append` methods, this is better for the JVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *optimize* your code, you should not switch to the Stream API. Instead, change it to use a single `Formatter`, instead of one for each element (hidden inside `String.format`) and avoid the temporary strings created by `String.format`:

```
public static StringBuilder printEmailsListFormat(List<String> a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        formatter.format("%-45s", a.get(i));
        if(i % 3 ==0) sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Given the simplicity of the format in this specific case, you may even eliminate the `Formatter` completely:

```
static final String EMPTY_CELL = String.format("%45s", ""); //JDK11: " ".repeat(45);

public static StringBuilder printEmailsListFormat(List<String> a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        String s = a.get(i);
        sb.append(s);
        if(s.length() < EMPTY_CELL.length())
            sb.append(EMPTY_CELL, s.length(), EMPTY_CELL.length());
        if(i % 3 ==0) sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is about the best you can do. It's pretty ugly, because streams are not aware of the list indices. It is not a very good candidate for converting to use streams.

```
public static StringBuilder printEmailsListFormat(ArrayList<String> a) {
    return IntStream.range(0, a.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> {
            String format = "%-45s";
            if (i % 3 == 0) format += "\n";
            return String.format(format, a.get(i));
        })
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append);
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `Collectors.joining` instead? Also, ternary `format = (i%3==0)? "..." : "...\n";` might be faster.

Comment: @tobias_k His original method returned the string builder. I suppose he could have been appending more information later so I just kept it the same.

Comment: I don’t see the point of adding the `"\n"` to the format instead of the result string. What if you used `.mapToObj(i -> { String s = String.format("%-45s", a.get(i)); if (i % 3 == 0) s += "\n"; return s; })` instead? Besides that, you can omit the `Collector.of` here, i.e. just use `.collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only parallelize and therefore speed up the formatting of the strings, but not the concatenation of the formatted parts, since they must be in order.

You could also concatenate the formatted parts via stream, but a for-loop is faster.
So you would get:

```
// just some example values
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"));
// formatting them in parallel
List<String> formatted = a.parallelStream().map(s -> String.format("%-45s", s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
// concatenating them in order
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (ListIterator<String> i = formatted.listIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    sb.append(i.next());
    if (i.previousIndex() % 3 == 0) {
        sb.append("\n");
    }
}
System.out.println("output: " + sb);
```

The output is:

```
output: string1                                      
string2                                      string3                                      string4                                      
string5
```

Remark: consider using System.getProperty("line.separator") instead of "\n".